# How to remove nodes from a xml doc in VBA

Tags: xml, vba, chilkat

Hi I'm having trouble removing a node from an XML doc.

E.G:

```
<XML>
<Node1>xxx</Node1>
<Node2>
    <Node3>zzz</Node3>
    <Node4>RemoveThis</Node4>
</Node2>
<Node2>
    <Node3>zzz</Node3>
    <Node4>RemoveThis</Node4>
</Node2>
</XML>
```

Im using code like this:

```
If oXml.ChilkatPath("Node1|*") = "xxx" Then
        oXml.RemoveChildWithContent("Node2|Node4|*")
        outFile.WriteLine(oXml.GetXml())
End If
```

If I use

```
oXml.ChilkatPath("Node2|Node4|*")
```

There's no problem getting the value "RemoveThis"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just read the documentation.  RemoveChildWithContent expect a string not node name.  So in your case, use RemoveChildWithContent("Remove This")

Comment: Okey, but I want to remove the whole node. Do you know how I should code in order to recive that?

Comment: Read the documentation? :). I have no experience with chilkat at all :). Good luck.

Comment: And RemoveChildWithContent only works on Node1. Can't remove the nodes under.

Comment: From your xml "Remove This" = node4, "xxx" = node1.  Did you use xxx or Remove This?  Do you want to remove node2 when node4 = Remove This?

Comment: I tried with both oXml.RemoveChildWithContent("xxx") - worked
oXml.RemoveChildWithContent("RemoveThis") - didn't work

I want to remove Node4 when Node1=xxx. But it seems that I can't go that "deep" in the nodes

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found on the documentation.  May not work as I don't have chilkat.

```
Set xBeginAfter = xml.GetSelf()
' xFound is a Chilkat_9_5_0.Xml
if xml.ChilkatPath("Node1|*") = "xxx" then
   Set xFound = xml.SearchAllForContent(xBeginAfter,"Remove This")
   Do While Not (xFound Is Nothing )
    xFound.RemoveFromTree
    Set xFound = xml.SearchAllForContent(xBeginAfter,"Remove This")
   Loop
end if
```